# Hand cursor pointer out of image bounds

Tags: html, css

Cursor becomes a pointer slightly out of image.

I have an image, and if you click on it, it brings you to another page but the cursor becomes a pointer slightly out of the image, how can I solve the problem so that it becomes a pointer only in the image bounds?

```css
.images {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.product-image {
  margin: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: solid grey;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
```

```html
<section class="images">
  <a href="image-link">
    <img class="product-image" src="image">
  </a>
</section>
```

Comment: Your `<img>` has both `margin` and `padding` and the `<a>` needs to accommodate that space. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and look at the box model of each element. Shouldn’t the `padding` be applied to the `<a>`?

Comment: Try removing the padding in product-image.